# postgres - bigint out of range error, which datatype to use for very large numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to store some hashes (originally in hexadecimal) but I cast them to int to save in pgsql but get

```
select 12347933502038296527::bigint

ERROR:  bigint out of range
********** Error **********
ERROR: bigint out of range
SQL state: 22003
```

I realize the number is too large for `int8`type, what data type should I be using instead of int8? would `decimal` work for my case? any other strategy that would work to save such large numbers?

Comment: Yes, you can use `decimal`/`numeric`. If you don't need to do arithmetic operations on those values, you can also use `bytea`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bigint's are pretty big.  It is unusual to need anything larger than that.  In most databases, that is as far as you can go with a native binary representation.  `Decimal`/`numeric` often allows a slightly larger precision.

Postgres, by contrast, supports `numeric`/`decimal` with basically unlimited precision, as explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html).

The following works directly:

```
select 12347933502038296527::decimal
```

If you want to be more specific:

```
select 12347933502038296527::decimal(20, 0)
```

That said, often such large numbers are used as ids.  In that case, you might want to use a string instead of a numeric representation.  A string has the advantage of keeping leading zeros, for instance.

Comment: @AlexW . . . Variable length keys have a small effect on index performance, so fixed-length keys are preferable.  However, if you need strings as the key, you need strings as the key.

Comment: *"It is unusual to need anything larger than that."* in crypto you routinely have big numbers since 10e18 wei = 1 ETH.